# selenium-RC: what is the best way of clearing the browser without restarting it

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm running many tests (on FF) one after the other and I would like each test to start off with a fresh browser (ie no cookies, no cache,..). One idea is to close the browser and open a fresh one for the new test (this will create a new profile and probably the cleanest environment possible).

This is causing too much trouble and taking too long so I'll give away some of the security of having a new profile for not closing the browser. How would you do such a thing? And is clearing the cookies enough?

Answer (score 2):

I know that ctrl+shift and refresh clears the cache and cookies, therefore after each test method you can initiate a refresh while pressing ctrl+shift.

Alternative solution would be to write a java script that deletes all the cookies and cache and run getEval script to run the java script after each test method.

Selenium RC also have a function deleteCookies which deletes all the cookies, you can call this method after each test so that selenium deletes the cookies.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the language driver you are using. Regardless, it should be something along the line of:

```
deleteCookie(cookieName, options)
```

Example:

```
deleteCookie('preferredColor', 'path=/')
```

For complete API reference see [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html)

In my case using PHP:

```
$this->deleteCookie('uagent', 'path=/');
```

If you instead want to delete every cookie use deleteAllVisibleCookies().

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java then you can simply use this in setUp() .

***selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies();***

Hope this works Fine

Answer (score -1):

did you get solutions of this ? I am interested to know.

What I am doing is Set "do not remember " option and close the browser every time I need fresh browser ....